# Android SDK: Button becomes colored when changing the background color on LinearLayout

Tags: android, button, colors, background, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout in an Android app I am creating now which contains a default button with gradient gray color. This LinearLayout is now white but when I try to change the background color to yellow the button also becomes yellow which I don't want to happen. I also tried to use a color image to set the background color on the LinearLayout but the same thing happens. How do I solve this problem? Here is the code:

```
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="@color/yellow">

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

SOLVED: Wait, it actually works now. while the buttons become colored and transparent in the layout view in Eclipse the buttons is unaffected when I run the app on the phone. I thought that it would display the same result when the app is runned. Strange how it become that way in the layout view...

Comment: How did you set the background for the button? Does it change to the grey gradient when it's pressed?

Comment: Yes but if I do that then the button will become completely flat and rectangle and its size will be wrapped to the size of the text inside it. The height of the layout will also wrapped to the minimized button.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you may set a gray background color  `android:background="#A4A4A4"` for button also..

Answer (score 0):

Just set the background on your button separately. You can use a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html), i.e. a different background for each state of the button (pressed, focused, etc) to make it compeletely custom.

Why the background color changes with the layout I'm not sure. It sounds like your button is default to transparant. Check your `style` and `theme` to make sure that's not affecting what's displayed.

Comment: Hmm I could either use the themes AppTheme or AppBaseTheme but it is still producing the same results. I couldnt find any particular in the styles.xml that could affect the appearance.